# SplashScreen is center cropping

Tags: android, splash-screen

For my app I am creating an Splash Screen using a drawable resource file consist of a layerlist having a colored background and a centered vector drawable for the logo.

**splash_screen.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/grey_700" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/splash_foreground"
        android:gravity="center" />
</layer-list>
```

**style.xml**

```
...

<style name="Theme.SplashScreen" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/grey_900</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
</style>

...
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
...

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.SplashScreen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

...
```

**splash_foreground.xml**

[image]

## Problem

the output should show `splash_foreground` centered in the screen while the background color is cropped all over the screen but is showing a splash screen centered cropped.

[image]

Comment: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen#dimensions

Comment: @AbdullahJaved have you read the documentation? the first line says that it is for newer Android versions (>12)... Or tell me how can I implement it on the SDK version below 31. This comment does not help me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69045019/7874746

Comment: @AbdullahJaved not that particularly but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72320117/16177121) helped, **THANKS**

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by using the new splash_screen API. all thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72320117/16177121)

### Solution

- **Add Splash Screen API in `build.gradle`**

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0'
```

- **Add this line before the application tag in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file**

```
<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="androidx.core.splashscreen" />
```

- **In `theme.xml` & `theme.xml (night)` create a new style with `Theme.SplashScreen` being parent**

```
<style name="Theme.App.Starting" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/grey_900</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/ic_app_foreground</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenIconBackgroundColor">@color/grey_700</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/grey_700</item>
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.LGConnect</item>
    </style>
```

- **Set application theme and Launcher Activity theme to the newly created style**

```
...
<application
...
   android:theme="@style/Theme.App.Starting"
...
      <activity
         ...
         android:theme="@style/Theme.App.Starting"
...
```

- **Inside `onCreate` method of `MainActivity` add this line**

```
...
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
      installSplashScreen()
...
```

Comment: Better Solution, just thought you used an extra Activty/Fragment to display your Splash Screen but when using the API this is significantly better...